# Determine why a webpage hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to perform regression tests on a website. Sometimes, the page will take a very long time to load (more than 4 minutes). I am using `page.waitForSelector()` in most cases, rather than wait for the whole page.

That could mean the page isn't loading in a reasonable time or the specific element isn't loading in a reasonable time. I think the website is using an Apache 2 server. Are there any tools or methods I could use to determine what is causing the page to hang for so long? I want the script to report the reason when catching the timeout exception.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference  -   devtools performance is the developer level tool for that

Comment: I like the network performance tools and I want to be able to have those values reported automatically by the puppeteer script. I'm not sure how to have puppeteer use devtools or collect performance metrics of a page.